# what is wrong with my standard deviation calculation?

Tags: java, loops, standard-deviation

my code to find standard deviation is wrong. my code is supposed to find standard deviation from user input. i typed in the numbers 1 2 3 and the standard deviation of this set of numbers is 1 but it printed 10 where did i go wrong. also i know i have a bunch of unused variables dont mind them.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class readFromKeyboard { 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        String inStr = input.next(); 
        int n;
        int i;
        int count=0; 
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
        double average=0;
        int sum;
        double deviation = 0;
        int total;
        int temp = 0;



        while (!inStr.equals("EOL")) { 
          count++; 
          n = Integer.parseInt(inStr); 
          min = Math.min(min, n);
          max = Math.max(max, n);
          System.out.printf("%d ", n); 
          inStr = input.next(); 
          average += n;
          temp += Math.pow(n - average, 2);

        } 

        deviation = temp
        average = average/count;

        System.out.println("\n The average of these numbers is " + average);
        System.out.printf("The list has %d numbers\n", count); 
        System.out.printf("The minimum of the list is %d\n", min);
        System.out.printf("The maximum of the list is %d\n", max);
        System.out.printf("The standard deviation of the list is %d\n", temp);

        input.close(); 


    } 
}
```

Comment: Within the loop, `average` is not actually the average, it is the cumulative sum. I think you need to calculate the deviation after you have the actual average

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you have written it to do, but your method of calculating the standard deviation is quite wrong. Have a read through this page and then rewrite your code (significantly) [Calculating Standard Deviation](https://www.strchr.com/standard_deviation_in_one_pass)

Comment: what is my code doing? i thought it was taking the first input number and subtracting the average then squaring them

Comment: Ermm ... your code is calculating something that is not the standard deviation.  Read the page that Erwin linked to.  Compare the code in that page to your code.

Comment: For a start, you are subtracting the average before you have calculated it (properly)!

Comment: *"also i know i have a bunch of unused variables dont mind them."*  -  Sorry, but that is the wrong attitude.  You should clean up the cruft *before* you ask someone to read your code.  For a start, the cruft *could* be the actual cause of your problems.

Comment: but its not cause it compiles if it were the main problem it wouldn't be in there obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFromKeyboard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String inStr = input.next();
        int n = 0;
        int i;
        int count = 0;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        double average = 0;
        int sum;
        double deviation = 0;
        int total;
        double temp = 0;// correction here because it must store double or float value

        ArrayList<Integer> n1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();// i used this to store all entered values

        while (!inStr.equals("EOL")) {
            count++;
            n = Integer.parseInt(inStr);
            min = Math.min(min, n);
            max = Math.max(max, n);
            System.out.printf("%d ", n);
            n1.add(n);
            inStr = input.next();
            average += n;

        }

        average = average / count; // this will give you final average

        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            temp += Math.pow(n1.get(j) - average, 2);
        }
        //System.out.println("\n" + temp + " " + count);
        deviation = Math.sqrt(temp / count); // this is your standard deviation

        //System.out.println(deviation);

        System.out.println("\n The average of these numbers is " + average);
        System.out.printf("The list has %d numbers\n", count);
        System.out.printf("The minimum of the list is %d\n", min);
        System.out.printf("The maximum of the list is %d\n", max);
        System.out.println("The standard deviation of the list is " + deviation);

        input.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: @markus standard deviation for your set 1 2 3 will be 0.8165

Comment: did you import "java.util.ArrayList"??

Comment: thank you that actually helped. but i dont understand waht you did and what it means

Answer (score 0):

Standard deviation for one variable is defined [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html). You have to take the square root of the mean of the sum of the squared differences between observations and the mean of the set.

```
//in the loop
temp += Math.pow(n - average, 2)
//outside the loop
deviation = Math.pow(temp/count,0.5) //or alternatively Math.sqrt()
```

This should give you what you need.